# Remove Configuration from VB2005 application

Tags: vb.net, compilation, configurationmanager

On the compile tab of the project properties:

If you look at the configuration dropdown it typically shows debug/release/active/all.

I attempted to add another option at one point in the build->configuration manager window, but decided that I didn't want to keep it. I removed it there, but it keeps showing up in the dropdown on the properties, as well as generates a folder by that name.

Does anyone know how to remove this? I can't find any "delete" or otherwise options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely just removed it at one level. Check the configuration manager on your Solution, and then on each of the projects within the Solution, and make sure it's removed from each.

(By going to the drop down, clicking , then remove just as you did before)

Comment: Additionally, I clicked in the section where it contains "project/configuration/platform/build", under the configuration, for some reason it still showed this additional option, I clicked Edit, and then Removed it in the next window that popped up.